# Apache2 server PHP access to files outside document root

Tags: php, apache-2.4, permissions, raspbian, nextcloud

I have a Raspberry Pi that I use to host a web server. I am using apache2 2.4.38, php8.1 and MariaDB 15.1 and I wanted to add a [Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/) server to it. I am using the web installer version. I already have an external USB HDD with BTRFS connected to the raspberry pi, and I have set it to automatically connect on startup using the `/etc/fstab` file. All of that is working perfectly. I created a directory on the drive, to store the nextcloud data. I configured the directory to be owned by the www-data user, so that Nextcloud could write to it. But this is where I ran into a problem. Both nextcloud and a simple php test file I made, give *permission denied* errors. I already have enabled Apache2 access to the directory by adding the following to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
<Directory /media/backup/nextcloud>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

(The drive is mounted at /media/backup and the directory I want to use is /media/backup/nextcloud/data. Both the nextcloud directory and the data directory are owned by www-data, the ones above them are owned by root)

I created a test file to trigger the error without having to re-enter a nextcloud password in the setup wizard every time and the php error log just gives a permission denied error. I got the info from the log using `tail -n 20 /var/log/apache2/error.log` and this is what the log says (with IP addresses censored of course):

```
[Sat Jun 04 22:38:46.485149 2022] [php:warn] [pid 1504] [client ____] PHP Warning:  include(/media/backup/nextcloud/data/cheese.txt): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/sus.php on line 2
[Sat Jun 04 22:38:46.485437 2022] [php:warn] [pid 1504] [client ____] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/media/backup/nextcloud/data/cheese.txt' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/sus.php on line 2
```

What makes this even weirder to me is that I *can* read from /usr/share (which is open to apache2 by default) with the same PHP script.

I don't know what to do. The permissions are 770, the directories exist and **are** writable by www-data, I tested that with `sudo -u www-data touch grass.txt`.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

### Details:

- OS: Raspbian lite 10 (buster), kernel 5.10.103-v7l+
- Device: Raspberry Pi 4B
- My PHP test file:
  `<?php include "/media/backup/nextcloud/data/cheese.txt";?>`
- The next cloud server is in `/var/www/nextcloud`, because I am planning on using a virtualhost in the future. For now, I am using a symlink in /var/www/html/cloud that points to /var/www/nextcloud. I thought maybe the symlink would be the problem, but after some thinking I realised that my test file **is** in `/var/www/html` and it has the same problem, so the symlink can't be the problem.
- Versions of used software:

  - apache2 2.4.38
  - php8.1
  - MariaDB 15.1
- `open_basedir` is not set, so that can't be it either

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after some further digging, I came across the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127400/apache-dont-work-on-media). The directories above the directory I wanted to read from should have execute rights. So I did `chmod +x /media /media/backup` and it worked.